# Stacking 2-d numpy arrays to get a 3-d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to stack a few 2-D arrays to obtain a 3-D array in python. My motivation behind doing this is to plot the spatial dependence of a variable: `var(x,y)` where `x` and `y` are two different dimensions, for different parameter values `param`. A minimum reproducible example for the same has been attached below:

```
while (param<=2):
 var(x,y)= fun  # fun is a function which returns var(x,y) as mentioned above
 param+=1
```

I want to keep on stacking the 2-D arrays `var(x,y)` for  different values of param, along a 3rd dimension. My output should be of the form :- `For param=0 : var(x,y), For param=1 : var(x,y), For param=2 : var(x,y)`. Any help regarding the construction of the 3-D array would be highly appreciated.
***Please note*** that var(x,y) is a 2-D array.

Comment: Usually we recommend collecting the arrays in a list, and doing one array construction step at the end.  Whether you  use `np.array`, `np.stack` or one of the other variations on `np.concatenate` depends on the desired shape(s).

Comment: But for this problem, I already have the 2d arrays ready. Could you suggest me how to reconstruct a 3d array from this.

Comment: Because I don't want to complicate things more. The reason for already having 2-d arrays built is that it gives a better physical essence to the problem in terms of the spatial dependence of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by hpaulj, the key idea is to have a list of the 2D arrays and then assemble them into a 3D array. It's usually more efficient to create the array in one go (no appending), so the following should be ideal:

```
import numpy as np

var_lst = []  # This is where you store the var arrays
while (param<=2):
    var = fun  # fun is a function which returns var(x,y) as mentioned above
    var_lst.append(var)
    param+=1

# Creates a 3D array with the following axes (x, y, param)
var_arr = np.stack(var_lst, 2)

# If later you want different axes, like (param, x, y), you can always swap them around with transpose
var_arr = var_arr.transpose(2, 0, 1)
```

Comment: With `np.stack` you  can chose the axis and skip the `swap`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question :- keeping up with generality, if I am sweeping ```param```  *** n*** number of times, then should I use ```var_arr=np.stack(var_list,(n-1))```, one more question:-  how do I access the elements of the 3-D array along the 3rd dimension. Will normal indexing technique work?

Comment: 1st question: no, the 2 in np.stack just indicated the axis on which the arrays within the list are to be stacked. For example, if `var(x,y)`  is a 2x2 array, and if param=n, by doing `var_arr = np.stack(var_lst, 2)` the shape of `var_arr` will be 2x2xn. If you were to do `var_arr = np.stack(var_lst, 0)`, the shape of `var_arr` would now be nx2x2, because you are stacking on the first axis.

2nd question: the normal indexing works, you if you want var(x, y) for param=3 you just do `var_arr[:, :, 3]`

Comment: My question was not for ``` param=n``` . I meant to ask : if i am sweeping the parameter a few times (let's say ```n``` number of times). The what should I do?